# How do I increase my logistics rating in The Last Starship?

Tags: the-last-starship

In [Introversion's game The Last Starship](https://www.introversion.co.uk/last-starship/), Alpha 3, some contracts can only be "Accept"ed when I have a rank/rating in logistics of at least 1. What in the game can I do, to pass this requirement?

I already gathered+sold Tillium ore, Precious Ore and their variants after smelting. Which only increased my Industry rank. Some of it was also part of contracts, which I delivered/completed.

Comment: I just received a bit of logisitcs XP for a "courier mission: deliver cargo to nearby star system". (Although I was sure I already did such missions without receiving xp.) Difficulty rating was 1.

Comment: The Tiddlet mission in Sector 1 (the sector after the "home" sector) gives enough logistics xp to increase rank.